# Measuring time in an assembler element in Anylogic,

Tags: time, anylogic

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNfdY.png)
I'm trying to measure time of expend of a piece in an assembler in AnyLogic,  I cannot use time measure start/end because the agent/part become a an assembled part.

I've using this two pieces of code without the "agent." I can see a some results but they do not make sense to me, is like is not considering the delay time i'm using in the assembler. I have allocated the codes at the start device and in the sink  but same results.

I also tried to adding some agent name but the error changes to the variable canno be resolved or is not a field

Those are the codes I'm using

timeOnGch=time()   (In the start element)
timeGchDist.add(time()-timeOnGch) (at the sink)

the suggestion the complete

[these are the complete codes Im using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/713jJ.png)

Comment: the code you are using is correct, so your problem is probably somewhere else... you are showing a service block, and you are saying your problem is an assembler... so it would be a better idea to show exactly what you did instead of something completely different

Comment: Hello, I used tie image to show the code I was using but my problem is how to measure time in a assembler.  just let me see how I paste an image here

Comment: it's the same exact way with the assembler